# ROR: Like button, no refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to make my like button change on click without refresh.

Model: like.rb

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tweet
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_tweet
  before_action :find_like, only: [:destroy]

  def create
    if already_liked?
      flash[:notice] = "You can't like more than once"
    else
      @tweet.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end

  def destroy
    if !already_liked?
      flash[:notice] = 'Cannot unlike'
    else
      @like.destroy
    end
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end

  private

  def find_tweet
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:tweet_id])
  end

  def find_like
    @like = @tweet.likes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def already_liked?
    Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, tweet_id:
    params[:tweet_id]).exists?
  end
end
```

In my view...

tweets/_tweets_index.html.erb

```
<% pre_like = tweet.likes.find { |like| like.user_id == current_user.id} %>
              <% if pre_like %>
                <%= link_to '<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>'.html_safe, tweet_like_path(tweet, pre_like), data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :delete }, :class => "like-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded-pill" %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>'.html_safe, tweet_likes_path(tweet), data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :post }, :class => "like-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded-pill" %>
              <% end %>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= tweet.likes.count %>
```

Routes

```
 resources :tweets do
    resources :comments
    resources :likes
    member do
      post :retweet
    end
  end
```

How can this be done? My like button works fine but i'm trying to get a no refresh on the button click. I have tried javascript and changed the controller accordingly but it says I don't have a destroy method? I'm at my wits end so have just gone back to the beginning like above.

How can I get this to work?

ty

Comment: Just a side note. Might wanna do something like `already_liked = tweet.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists?` to see if current user has liked already.

Answer (score -1):

Check out ActionCable. It supports Websockets which simply means that two endpoints communicate through a channel. You first create a connection between the server and the client. Then when the like button is hit the corresponding action is called. However, you have to alter the code in the action so that it doesn't render the page again, but broadcast a message to the channel mentioned previously. The client receives this message and by using Javascript it updates the counter of the button.

You should first generate a channel by using:

```
rails generate channel likes
```

Some files will be generated. Find the file

```
app/channels/likes_channel.rb
```

uncomment the line in the subscribed method and change the name of the channel to what you want.

Then, in your controller action add the line:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast("name_of_your_channel", message)
```

This way you broadcast the message to the channel.

Finally, pick the message in the file:

```
app/javascript/channels/likes_channel.js
```

at the `function received(data)`. The variable data hold the messages that were transmitted to the channel you subscribed.

This is just a very simple example and you might need to do more work. Please, read the documentation or some online tutorial.